# Angular app white page in Chrome but works in Safari & Firefox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on an angular web application.

I was usually debugging on chrome but, since some time(can't point exactly the moment), chrome would randomly render blank page (white page) on page refresh - only on my local environment.
Still, it worked without a problem when deployed to AWS S3.

As the problem got more serious, I started debugging on Safari.
The app works without issues on Firefox and Safari (both locally, and when hosted on AWS S3).

But after the last deploy to AWS S3, the app stopped working on S3 - I get a blank page, with some errors/warnings in the console (maybe not relevant at all).

As I tought it should be a compatibiliy issue, I updated some angular dependencies to match another angular project that was working on.

`ng version` output:

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.7
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13 
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 14.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1400.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular      14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core               14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         14.0.7
@angular/cdk                       14.2.7
@angular/cli                       14.0.7
@angular/flex-layout               14.0.0-beta.40
@angular/google-maps               14.1.1
@angular/material                  14.2.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   14.0.0
@schematics/angular                14.0.7
rxjs                               7.5.7
typescript                         4.7.4
```

`node --version` - `v14.17.0`

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "activtours-b2c-fe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@halloverden/ngx-cookiebot": "^1.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/facebook-js-sdk": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/google.accounts": "^0.0.6",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-in-viewport": "^13.0.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-date-fns": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-facebook": "^3.0.0-0",
    "ngx-filesaver": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-translate": "github:ngx-translate/core",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.7",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Chrome console output on page load[image: chrome console screenshot]

Result: white screen

Any ideas on how to fix/debug the issue?

Thanks a lot

I tried updating the versions of the `ng version` output to match another app that is working.